# url given by RewriteRule with variable request "file" in url instead of file in RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To be honest I'm new to htaccess and my problem is when I want to access a link, while using htaccess rewriterule with a variable, it gives me a 404 error, since it wants to access to the variable as the file instead of the given one in the htaccess:

link looks like this:
example.com/folder/variable

in the htaccess it looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Satisfy any
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^folder/([0-9a-z-A-Z-_]+)/$ folder/file.php?title=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

In theory it should work, as it work, but for me it doesn't.
I tried to rewrite this code a "few" times, used lots of working codes for others to make mine working without any luck.
In my httdp.conf file I changed AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All, I also checked if rewrite_module is active, and it is and it's working perfectly without variable.
Also have a htaccess file with Satisfy any code in my folder.

I hope I (we) can troubleshoot this error in my code.
Thanks for your future help and for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the mistake, here's the correct line ( / before $ made it not working):

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([0-9a-z-A-Z-_]+)$ folder/file.php?title=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```